# Calculating Next 6 Sessions From Just Day Of Week And Start Time in Django and Python

Tags: python, django, datetime, dayofweek

I have a python view in the Django Framework which has access to a database with a table Called Sessions in this table I have the day of the week and the start time. What I want to do is get the next 6 sessions based on the current date and time for my website.

```
sessions = []
for i in range(7):
    dow = (int(day_of_week) + i)
    dow_mod = dow % 7
    week_numb_mod = week_numb
    if dow >= 7:
        week_numb_mod = week_numb + 1
    begin_code = str(now.year) + "-W" + str(week_numb_mod)
    begin_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(begin_code + '-0', "%Y-W%W-%w")
    actual_date = begin_date + datetime.timedelta(days=dow_mod)
    for record in Session.objects.filter(day_of_week=dow_mod):
        actual_datetime = datetime.datetime.combine(actual_date, record.start_time)
        if now < actual_datetime:
            sessions.append(record)
sessions = sessions[:6]
```

For some reason when I am in mid week the actual_date jumps forward a week and I can't seem to figure it out. If any one knows where I went wrong or knows of a simpler way of doing this the help would be appreciate.

Comment: now = datetime.datetime.now()
 day_of_week = now.strftime("%w")
 week_numb = now.isocalendar()[1]

Sorry this might help.